# How to Write Data (String) to Text File

Tags: java, sql, io

I currently have the lines of code:

```
ResultSet RS = cs.executeQuery();
....
FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
while(RS.next()) {
    outFile.write(RS.getString(1));
}
```

**There is only one column in the resultset.** I'm getting an error that RS.getString(1) must be an int.

Comment: You are using this method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileOutputStream#write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28int%29) expects an `int` value. You could simply use a `PrintWriter` here instead which has an [overloaded `write` method for writing `String` values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String%29):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, false));
writer.write(...);
```

or to write each `String` on a new line use [println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29)

```
writer.println(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease try it.

```
     public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException{
    File file=new File("C:\\file.txt");
    String text="myText";
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(file);
    fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();

}
```